# MySQL Query output using if else or case..?

Tags: mysql

I have a table as

```
mysql> select * FROM testa;
+---------+-------+
| month_x | money |
+---------+-------+
| 11101   | 12345 |
| 11105   |   100 |
| 11105   |   100 |
| 11105   |   100 |
| 11105   |   100 |
| 11106   | 12345 |
+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

where last two digits in the month_x are months now i want my output as

```
Month   TOTAL
01  12345
02  0
03  0
04  0
05  400
06  12345
07  0
08  0
09  0
10  0
11  0
12  0
```

IS possible using the If else or case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to create a table first with months' numeric value in it.

```
CREATE TABLE `months` (
  `mon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
INSERT INTO `months` VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);
```

Then execute this query,

```
SELECT m.mon, 
       IF(Sum(t.money) IS NULL, 0, Sum(t.money)) AS `money` 
FROM   testa t 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN months m 
         ON ( t.month_x%100 = m.mon ) 
GROUP  BY m.mon;
```

Result is,

```
+------+-------+
| mon  | money |
+------+-------+
|    1 | 12345 |
|    2 |     0 |
|    3 |     0 |
|    4 |     0 |
|    5 |   400 |
|    6 | 12345 |
|    7 |     0 |
|    8 |     0 |
|    9 |     0 |
|   10 |     0 |
|   11 |     0 |
|   12 |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Is it not possible to it with that single table..??

Comment: No. That's not possible. You can put the whole thing in a procedure however. But creating temporary table every-time for such query will decrease the performance. That's why its better to have such permanent table

Answer (score 2):

You can use [modular arithmetic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) to obtain the trailing two digits (they're the remainder when the number is divided by 100), then assuming you wish to sum `money` when your data is "grouped by" month:

```
SELECT month_x % 100 AS Month, SUM(money) AS TOTAL
FROM testa
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY Month ASC;
```

Alternatively, you could use rely on MySQL's [implicit type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) and use its string functions:

```
SELECT RIGHT(month_x, 2) AS Month, SUM(money) AS TOTAL
FROM testa
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY Month ASC;
```

---

**UPDATE**

As @shiplu.mokadd.im states, to show every month (even those for which you have no data), you need to obtain numbers 1 through 12 from a temporary table.  However, you can create such a temporary table in your query using `UNION`:

```
      SELECT 1
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3 -- etc
```

Therefore:

```
SELECT Month, Sum(money) AS TOTAL
FROM   testa
  RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT  1 AS Month
  UNION SELECT  2 UNION SELECT  3 UNION SELECT  4 UNION SELECT  5 UNION SELECT  6
  UNION SELECT  7 UNION SELECT  8 UNION SELECT  9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11
  UNION SELECT 12
  ) months ON testa.month_x % 100 = months.Month
GROUP BY Month;
```

**HOWEVER** I would note that *usually* one doesn't usually do this in the database, as it really belongs in the presentation layer: from whatever language you're accessing the database, you'd loop over `1...12` and assume `TOTAL` to be `0` if there's no corresponding record in the resultset.

Comment: It is ok.but i want if the month is not present as in my actual table the 01,05,06 are present but there are twelve months in year so if that is not in the base table it should be in output with sum as 0.As i have given the sample output pattern

Comment: @AbdulManaf It can only be done by using a temporary table. See my answer.

Comment: @AbdulManaf: See alternative in my revised answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF statements - yes.
Look @ this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html